# Unbound local error variable 'streak' referenced before assignment (while using tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I ran into this error while making a rock, paper, scissors game.

```
File "test.py", line 87, in <module>

sp()

File "test.py", line 78, in sp

streak += 1

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'streak' referenced before assignment
```

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Paper, scissors, rock")
window.geometry("1050x700")
window.resizable(False, False)

streak = 0

def sp():
    frm2 = tk.Frame(master = window, width = 1050, height = 700)
    player_play = tk.Label(master = frm2, text = "You played scissors!", font = ("helvetica", 30))
    player_play.place(x = 370, y = 100)
    enmy_play = tk.Label(master = frm2, text = "The computer played paper!", font = ("helvetica", 30))
    enmy_play.place(x = 280, y = 200)
    text = tk.Label(master = frm2, text = "You win!", font = ("helvetica", 25))
    text.place(x = 470, y = 300)
    streak += 1
    streak_wdgt = tk.Label(master = frm2, text = str("Winning streak: ") + str(streak), font = ("helvetica", 15))
    streak_wdgt.place(x = 870, y = 1)
    play_again = tk.Button(master = frm2, width = 20, height = 4, bg = "black", fg = "white", text = "Play Again", command = play_again_cmd)
    play_again.place(x = 440, y = 400)
    exit_btn = tk.Button(master = frm2, width = 20, height = 4, bg = "black", fg = "white", text = "Exit Game", command = exit_btn_cmd)
    exit_btn.place(x = 440, y = 500)
    frm2.pack()

sp()

window.mainloop()
```

I tried making it a global variable which didn't work, I tried putting the variable inside the function however this makes it so that the variable resets every time the function is run which is not desirable. I need it to be inside a function otherwise tkinter won't assign it to a button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Making it a global variable should have worked. Did you put the `global streak` statement in the function? It doesn't do anything if you put it outside the function.

Comment: To update the streak variable outside of your function scope you need to add `global streak` to the top of your function. This is considered poor form. You should refactor your code so that you don't need to update values outside of your function. Why is this a function at all?